# how does the spring dispatcher servlet contacts the defaultHandler property of a handlerMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Let's suppose that I got this configuration in my web application context:

```
<bean id="handlerMappings" parent="webframeworkHandlerMappings">        
    <property name="order" value="0" />        
    <property name="defaultHandler">        
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

`UrlFilenameViewController` will be contacted by the dispatcher as a `handlerMapping` or as a controller?

Comment: Neither... As a handler... A handler in this case is a controller. But the dispatcherservlet knowns nothing about controllers only handlers. It asks the `HandlerMapping`s configured for a handler to proces the incoming request, which handler that is the dispatcherservlet doesn't care...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One stage in the DispatcherServlet workflow is to find a controller using the HandlerMapping. Once found it will let the Controller.handleRequest method process the request. So to answer your question it will seek a HandlerMapping which is a Controller